# Attempts to use curl in conjunction with api give 404 error

Tags: python, json, api, jira, confluence

I am attempting to query Confluence knowledge base pages using the API and failing.

I have researched the api and have the following:

**Browsing Content**

```
curl -u admin:admin http://localhost:8080/confluence/rest/api/content/ | python -mjson.tool
```

**Read Content and Expand the Body:**

```
curl -u admin:admin http://localhost:8080/confluence/rest/api/content/3965072?expand=body.storage | python -mjson.tool
```

What I actually want to do is dump out the contents of a page / pages in a "Space" as Confluence calls it to a file, or on screen.

This is an actual page:

"https://bob.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BKB/pages/1234567/BOB+KNOWLEDGE+BANK"

And this is an example I found of using the REST API to do what I want:

```
curl -u admin:admin -G "http://myinstance.address:8090/rest/api/content/search" --data-urlencode "cql=(type=page and space=low and title ~ "LOWERTOWN")" \ | python -m json.tool
```

**How I am translating what I have researched:**

```
curl -u "bob@bob.com:12345678" -G "https://bob.atlassian.net/rest/api/content/search" --data-urlencode "cql=(type=page and space=BKB and title ~ "BOB+KNOWLEDGE+BANK")" \ | python -m json.tool
```

Which results in this error:

```
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
No JSON object could be decoded
```

I have grabbed my logic here from this site:

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Confluence-questions/How-to-get-Conflunece-knowledge-base-data-through-API/qaq-p/1030159

And I am assuming I have misunderstood this:

```
/rest/api/content/search
```

And where it belongs in my curl statement and linking it to the knowledge base. I am also unsure if applying the -mjson.tool is applicable in my case or if I actually have it installed / need to verify that.

Can you help me interpret this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there! You just need to pass `cql` as query parameter to the service as mentioned [here in Atlassian documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/confluence/rest/api-group-search/#api-wiki-rest-api-search-get):

> curl --request GET 
> --url 'https://your-domain.atlassian.net/wiki/rest/api/search?cql={cql}' 
> --header 'Authorization: Bearer <access_token>' 
> --header 'Accept: application/json'

Comment: Thank you - this is great do you know how I can search for a particular string within a Space or page, or even group of pages?